# Is assembly different than 8-bit always wrong choice for beginner?

Tags: assembly

I want to learn some assembly language. My goal is to learn x86 assembly, but I know it may be too complicated for a very start. On a daily basis I use C++ and some Java, so assembly is not my first choice ever, but I would like to have some fun with it and I have heard that 8-bit assembly is something I should aim at the very beginning. The point is I would like to start with 16-bit one. Is it much more complicated than 8-bit? I just have an opportunity to code for physical machine which uses 16-bit assembly which would be easier for me to see results.

Comment: Off-topic, but my two-cents: 8, 16, 32, 64 bits is going to make little difference. Newer ISAs may carry over legacies from previous ones, eventually it may be good to figure out the "why"s. BTW, chances are that you also have a machine which uses 64-bit x86 assembly :)

Comment: 8-bit ISAs are often "weird" because a register can't hold a full pointer.  They don't fit the C/Java machine model very well.  [Why do C to Z80 compilers produce poor code?](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6095).  I wouldn't recommend it, unless you mean a toy ISA like LC-3.  But still I'd recommend MIPS with the MARS simulator if for some reason you don't want to just learn x86 32-bit or 64-bit.  I would absolutely *not* recommend learning 16-bit x86 with real-mode segmentation and legacy DOS/BIOS stuff first (or at all), that's nothing like modern programming but not simpler.

Comment: Or ARM is another clean-ish ISA that's easy to program form, and has some neat features you can learn about.  (Like addressing modes that write back the address to the register as well as doing a load or store.  And in 32-bit, predicated instructions.  And a barrel shifter for source registers as part of any instruction.  Neat things that compilers can take advantage of to make efficient asm.)

Comment: I would recommend starting with a simple 32 bit assembly. MIPS and x86 are good places to start. As others have mentioned, in a 32 bit address space you need a 32 bit register to store the value of an address. Working with 8 bit assembly might actually be more complicated since there are strange things happening at that level. If you are truly new to assembly, look into MIPS which is a Reduced Instruction Set Computer (RISC) Architecture. Then work your way to x86 by disassembling simple programs you write. Good luck!

Comment: 8-bit architectures have the advantages of still being relevant, and one of the few practical places significant amounts of assembly gets written any more. Learning AVR or 8051 assembly could actually be useful. On the other hand 16-bit CPUs aren't really used for anything any more. The problem with MIPS is that the modern MIPS architecture that is used today has some key differences from the obsolete original MIPS architecture that everything on the web will try to teach you..

Comment: I would avoid mips and x86 and risc-v as a first one, make x86 your last one which could mean never.  msp430  and pdp-11 (lsi-11) are very good first choices, there are tools and places to run that code.  arm thumb for various reasons is good after one or both of those.   Then its wide open risc-v, mips, avr, pic, lc-3, and many others, then mess with cisc like 6502, 8051  and the very last x86 starting with the original 8086/88 on an emulator (emulate all of these, far greater chance of success, save hardware for much later), likewise avoid armv7 and armv8 until armv4-6 are known.

Comment: once you learn a good one like msp430 or pdp-11 not the language nuances itself but the instruction set architecture.  Then each new one you add gets much easier.  I recommend writing emulators or disassemblers or both, msp430 is a couple hours to an afternoon and there are gnu tools to use to beat up on it.  pdp-11 the same an afternoon.  risc-v  rv32i an afternoon, rv32c same, very easy to write a disassembler/emulator for and you will learn it pretty well and gnu compiler tools to answer questions and beat up on it.  then you will know these better than most folks that use them daily.

Comment: 4,8,16,18,32,36,... arent really the issue, you want an instruction set with a good mix of instructions and somewhat orthogonal and that makes sense, and okay documentation.   And most importantly existing easy to come by tools.  generally something supported by binutils and gcc (a laundry list including pdp-11, msp430, mips, arm, x86, risc-v to name a few).  the assembler by itself will answer many questions about the toolchain, how is the offset computed for these instructions being a big one not usually well documented.

Comment: If you have a PC and a C compiler, one advantage of using X86, is you can use most C compilers to convert code from C to assembly, although optimization may make the code a bit more complicated. Doing a non-optimized compile should keep the code simple.

Comment: @rcgldr: I don't consider store/reload after every C statement to be "simple".  Write smaller functions when you're just learning.  Disable auto-vectorization and loop-unrolling, but enable optimization, at least `-O1` or `-Og` if not `gcc -O3 -fno-unroll-loops -fno-tree-vectorize`.  But yes, the main argument in favour of x86 is that it's an ISA you probably care about / want to know about.  It's not too complicated if you don't try to write your own OS, and just learn user-space programming under an OS like Linux.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I don't understand what you mean by `store/reload after every C statement`. One concern about optimization is the compiler taking advantage of register dependencies and reordering of the generated code, which could be confusing to a beginner.

Comment: @rcgldr: you said "Doing a non-optimized compile should keep the code simple."  Non-optimized code compiles every C statement separately, effectively treating non-`register` variables kind of like `volatile`.  If you've ever actually read non-optimized code, it's a huge clutter of memory operands and loads/stores, even with CISC x86 for memory sources.  It looks nothing like what you'd write by hand and is super-bloated, making it harder to follow.  `gcc -fverbose-asm` can help, though.  Compare https://godbolt.org/z/YaOvou gcc `-Og`  vs `-O0` 3x longer and a huge mess.

Comment: @rcgldr: see [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) for more about exactly why `-O0` doesn't keep anything in registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I wasn't aware of this issue. I was thinking of the code generated by old Microsoft compilers. I haven't checked what Visual Studio generates. Is there an option to optimize, but without reordering, such as specifying target processor type?

Comment: @rcgldr: Not exactly, but `gcc -Og` is minimal optimization (intended for edit/compile/test cycles).  Any reordering will be minor, and it shouldn't restructure your code much.  It doesn't even turn `for()` loops into `if();  do{}while()`, as you can see in that Godbolt link.  It also didn't optimize away the loop counter, and is redoing sign-extension from int to pointer-width every iteration.  When you're just learning asm, you'll want to start with simple functions that don't have many statements total.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)